# XAML Based Level Editor

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I would like to create a level editor for Silverlight with XAML.  What resources would be useful for research before starting such a project?

Here is some information to clarify.
I made 1 silverlight game and released it so far. 
The I would like to have an overhead style action game.  The map would be much larger than the current viewable space.

Comment: How much Silverlight experience do you have? What sort of levels (2D tile-based, full 3D)?

Comment: Which game(s) are you targetting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF has a steep learning curve, don't get dis-heartened it's brilliant, but it has so many nooks and corners that it'll take a while to get comfortable. For a start there's a really good blogging community at [WPFDisciples](https://wpfdisciples.wordpress.com/) all of these are worth reading. [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=wpf) has some good libaries for 3D, physics engines etc and reverse engineering others code is a good way to learn.

A couple of good books are [Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) and Petzold's [Applications = code + markup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619573) is one of the few books/places that doesn't preach that everything has to be done in Xaml

An area that takes some getting used to is [binding](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111083249/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2007/10/08/115938.aspx), lots of stuff out there but it can be complex, and it's a [impossible to debug until you have the magic knowledge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/). Binding in WPF isn't just about data, it's about linking all UI elements and behaviours together - it's really important.

Finally you have a choice between Silverlight and WPF, they're not the same. Although Silverlight is a good sub set of WPF, there are certain things you just can't do.

Finally Finally if you have a graphic design, artist background try using [Blend](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512023612/http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/overview.aspx?key=blend), not VS it's a much better tool for those who are visually aware.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously getting to grips with XAML and how to work with it as a concept is important if you haven't already. An overview of it (using WPF as the example) can be found at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) along with the [System.Windows.Markup namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.aspx) which has the classes you would use for working with it.